# what are the specific frustum planes, when set from camera matrix?

Tags: three.js

I create my frustum like this:

```
var frustum = new THREE.Frustum();
frustum.setFromMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().multiply(camera.projectionMatrix, camera.matrixWorldInverse));
```

but the frustum planes property is just an array.

I need to get the specific planes of a frustum, ie what plane of the frustum planes is the near plane, far plane, etc... what order are they in?

Comment: i found in threejs source that the orthographic camera constructor is   OrthographicCamera( left, right, top, bottom, near, far ), so i suppose that would be the order of the frustum planes?

Comment: ... and in the perspective camera source i see:   this.projectionMatrix.makeFrustum(
left, left + width, top - height, top, near, this.far ); ... but that would mean an order of left, right, bottom, top, near , far.  Thus with bottom and top reversed compared to orthographic... So which is the correct order?

Comment: Can you investigate your scene, zoom around a bit, and deduce?